# Is Sapphire crystal flexible?

Tags: material-science

It is widely rumoured that the next iPhone's screen cover will be a sheet of synthetic Sapphire crystal. [A video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5R0_FJ4r73s) purporting to show a leaked part has emerged.

The chap in the video (Marques Brownlee) talks about the optical quality of the screen, its scratch resistance and lastly, its flexibility.

The screen seems to be about 1mm thick.

To my eyes, he's not really "going for it" when he tries to scratch the screen, but he does definitely bend it to an extreme degree. The bending can be [seen here](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=5R0_FJ4r73s&t=2m59s) – I find it excruciating to watch because I'm imagining it as glass and thinking about what it will do to his hands it if cracks.

I'm curious: is Sapphire crystal actually flexible to this degree? If it's not, then the whole video, or the featured part must be a hoax or a fake.

Comment: I would think most everything that is a few microns thick is pliable to some degree (depending, obviously on the length and width in relation to the thickness).

Comment: It is the hardest substance next to diamond. How hard should he try to scratch it?

Comment: @C.TowneSpringer :-) If it's that hard, then he could be trying harder! It just looks like he pulls his punches.

Comment: @KyleKanos In the video he describes it as "paper thin" while holding it edge on. It's clearly not paper thin, it looks about 1mm.

Comment: It might be a polycarbonate with a layter of saphire sputtered on or something like that. Anyway, saphire is aluminum oxide (and ruby and corundum and alumina - melts at about 2100 C). BTW, diamonds will oxidize and disapear in a home oven.